# What's the difference between grism and grating?

Tags: observational-astronomy

In spectroscopic observations, sometimes you meet grism, sometimes grating.

Both of them could cause light dispersion, but what is the difference?

Comment: Grism: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grism

Comment: I know that link.  What is the function of a prism?  A prism itself is enough to disperse light.

Comment: They disperse light with different dispersion functions, allowing astronomers to see different spectral features.

Answer (score 1):

Transmission gratings on their own introduce chromatic aberration.  This is because they change the effective focal length and do so as a function of wavelength.  The chromatic aberration can be eliminated by introducing a prism of the correct dispersion.  Known as a grism, the grating/prism combination provides an unaberrated image at the 0th order in addition to the spectrum, although the spectrum has fairly low resolution.